# recursive levels and loop counting

Tags: java, loops, recursion, counting

I have a homework assignment that I am ready to turn in, in the assignment I had to use recursion to draw nested circles 10 levels deep, after banging my head against this for a few hours I finally completed it. My only question is, is the image I am drawing 10 levels deep or actually 11?

This question comes from the fact that I have specifically state the recursion to end when it has gone through 10 levels, but I do tell the method to draw the original circles then it calls itself. this is making me think that it draws the first level then goes down 10 to make a total of 11 levels. the Image it creates goes down so far that I can not count the circles :/

any clarification would be appreciated, thanks!

```
    // import statements
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class RecursiveCircles 
    {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // create a new canvas
    RCanvas myCanvas = new RCanvas();

    // create JFrame
    JFrame myJframe = new JFrame();
    myJframe.setTitle("Recursive Circles");

    // set JFrame size, location and close operation
    myJframe.setSize(1500, 500);
    myJframe.setLocation(100, 100);
    myJframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // and canvas to JFrame and make it visble
    myJframe.getContentPane().add(myCanvas);
    myJframe.setVisible(true);

     } // end main          
   } // end class RecursiveCircles

    /*
     * this class will draw the main circle of the image and will have the recursive
     * method that draws the two outer circles down 10 levels
     */

    class RCanvas extends Canvas 
    {
   // defualt constructor 
   public RCanvas ()
   {}

   public void paint (Graphics graphics)
   { 
       // declare variables
       String title = "Recursive Circles";

       int n = 300; // diamerter of the circle
       int xOrigin = 600; // x location of start of circle (makes circle around the origin I wanted
       int yOrigin = 100; // y location of start of circle (makes circle around the origin i wanted
       int radius = n/2; // radius of circle (half the diamerter

       int level = 10;

       // make canvas background color black
       graphics.setColor(Color.black); // make the background color black
       graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 1500, 500); // rectangle that fills the JFrame

       // put title on canvas
       graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       graphics.drawString(title, 725, 50);

       // draw main circle
       graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
       graphics.drawOval(xOrigin, yOrigin, n, n);   

      drawRCircles(graphics,xOrigin,yOrigin,radius,level); // call recrusrive method
       System.out.println(level);

   } // end paint

   /*
    * This is the recursive method that will draw the two circles on the outer sides of the
    * main circle. it will then call itself and repate the process till it is 10 levels deep
    */
   public void drawRCircles(Graphics graphics,int xOrigin,int yOrigin, int radius, int level)
   {

   int newRadius = (radius/2); // radius of smaller circle
   int newXOrigin = xOrigin - (newRadius); // xOrigin of circle on left of the main circle
   int newYOrigin = yOrigin + (newRadius); // yOrigin of circle on the right of the main circle
   int newXOrigin2 = xOrigin + (newRadius*3); // xOrigin of circle on the right of the main circle
   int newYOrigin2 = yOrigin + (newRadius); // yOrigin of circle on the right of the main circle
       if (level > 0) // counts down from 10 to make the recursive image 10 levels deep
       { 
           graphics.drawOval(newXOrigin, newYOrigin, newRadius*2, newRadius*2); // draw recursive circle on the left of main circle
           graphics.drawOval(newXOrigin2, newYOrigin2, newRadius*2, newRadius*2); // draw recursive circle on the right of main circle
           drawRCircles(graphics, newXOrigin, newYOrigin , newRadius, (level-1)); // make recursion of left circle
           drawRCircles(graphics, newXOrigin2, newYOrigin2,newRadius,(level-1)); // make recursion of right circle

       }// end if
   } // end drawRCircles
  }// end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is drawing 11 circles but your call(s) to the `drawRCircles` itself is responsible for only 10 of them.

More specifically, these lines are drawing 1 circle.

```
    // draw main circle
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.drawOval(xOrigin, yOrigin, n, n);
```

This circle gets drawn regardless of whether or not you even have a `drawRCircles` function. (Try removing it and running your code to see what happens.)

Then, your code *calls* the `drawRCircles` function 11 times, but only *draws* 10 circles since the last call to it, with level = 0 fails the test `if(level > 0)`.

> the Image it creates goes down so far that I can not count the circles :/

A quick tip: since you want to know if, given max level of `N`, will it draw `N` or `N+1` levels of circles, you could also just try changing your `level` variable to something more manageable (like 2) and checking it visually.

Going back to your code above, and ignoring the `draw main circle` portion (since it's independent of your recursive circle drawing) you have

```
    drawRCircles(graphics,xOrigin,yOrigin,radius,level); // call recursive method
    System.out.println(level);
```

and within your `public void drawRCircles(…)` function,

```
    drawRCircles(…,level-1);
```

Let's check it with level = 2 instead of 10:

```
    drawRCircles(…, 2) 
        --> Check if 1 > 0.  
            --> Yes, 1 > 0 so drawRCircles(…, 1) 
                -->  Check if 0 > 0.
                    --> No, 0 = 0, so stop.
```

Number of levels = 2 = number of recursive circles drawn.

Comment: thanks for the info! both posted solutions work but I am going to mark yours as the correct answer because you also delved a little deeper into it and gave some pointers, thanks :D